# Does kioptrix work only on virtual machines?

Tags: kali-linux

While practicing the vulnhub kioptrix, I have a question. Does it only work in virtual machines? Is it structurally designed from the beginning?

Is there a way to make it work on Cali Linux instead of virtual machines? Even if you google it, it only explains how to download the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Kioptrix machine here.

It is only a Virtual Machine - I have not seen anything else.

You need a good Virtual App because you would probably want to use USB pass through to have a separate USB wireless card for vulnerability testing.

Kioptrix is largely limited to what it says because it is a prepackaged VM.

I use Kali instead and find it to be more flexible (real machine or virtual)

Kali is a Linux system that is tailored to forensics and vulnerability testing. You can make a real Kali machine by installing it on a computer (not recommended for most people) or install it as a virtual machine (I do this).

Now for Kioptrix or Kali (or other distributions)  you need an internet connection. If you are trying to get into some other network (that is what this activity is about) then you need an internet connection that is somewhat harder to trace (say USB Wireless). So you need a way to connect the USB card and that needs USB pass through.  VMware Workstation allows this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a 20-year-old Korean university student, so I am still using a translator because my English is not good. Can you explain it more easily?

Comment: I added some additional explanation as clearly as I could.

Comment: If your question has been reasonably been answered, you can mark the answer if you wish.

Comment: I don't understand perfectly yet, but I think I know the feeling. Thank you so much for your answer